# Can it be that Liststyle .sidebar on macOS disables .onDelete?

Tags: list, swiftui, sidebar

macOS: It seems like setting `.listStyle(.sidebar)` disables the deletion of list cells on swipe. Why is that and how could a workaround look like?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var numbers: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) { i in
                Text("item \(i)")
            }
            .onDelete(perform: removeRows)
        }
//        .listStyle(.sidebar) // uncomment this line
    }
    
    func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        numbers.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it both ways and it did not work either way. Xcode 13.2.1, MacOS 12.1.

Comment: It did NOT work with the regular list??? I'm on Xcode 13.2.1 and MacOS 12.2b ... regular works, .sidebar does not.

Comment: I deleted last. I finally got it to work with the swipe. Not sure why it wouldn't before...  And yes, it appears that `.sidebar` stops `.onDelete` from working.

Comment: maybe Apple does't want people to delete things in the sidebar ... as it is more of a navigation area

Comment: You may be right, but it is not documented that I could find.